# How can I tell Emscripten to log which functions it handled with Asyncify?

Tags: emscripten

Emscripten's old Emterpreter mode had a setting `EMTERPRETIFY_ADVISE` that would output which functions it had identified needed to be converted for use with the Emterpreter.

In the new Asyncify mode, how can I get a similar list of functions which had to be instrumented/handled with Asyncify? I've checked [the docs](https://emscripten.org/docs/porting/asyncify.html) and [settings.js](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/blob/master/src/settings.js), but couldn't see anything like `EMTERPRETIFY_ADVISE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Emscripten 2.0.5 the `ASYNCIFY_ADVISE` setting will output a list of functions which Asyncify will transform.

```
-s ASYNCIFY_ADVISE=1
```

If you need to use an earlier version of Emscripten, you can compile with these settings:

```
-s BINARYEN_EXTRA_PASSES='--pass-arg=asyncify-verbose' --profiling
```

```
[asyncify] stream_hexnum can change the state due to glk_put_char
[asyncify] write_long can change the state due to write_buffer
[asyncify] write_byte can change the state due to write_buffer
[asyncify] write_heapstate_sub can change the state due to write_buffer
[asyncify] write_short can change the state due to write_buffer
[asyncify] glulxe_classtable_unregister can change the state due to classes_remove
```